# Deep state redirects for Angular4+

Tags: angular, redirect, router

is there any library which can help implementation of Deep State Redirects in Angular 4+.
Basically looking for exactly like https://github.com/ui-router/dsr in Angular 4+

> > With Deep State Redirect, a parent state remembers whatever child state was last activated. When the user directly reactivates the parent state, they are redirected to the nested state (which was previously activated).